# Windows 7 - Hyper-V - Boot manager failed to find OS Loader

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, boot, hyper-v

This virtual machine has worked before but when switching between computers something happened with the file. When starting the Windows 7 virtual machine I get the following error on both computers:

[image]

Startup Repair starts after the `Windows is loading files...` has stopped showing and the green bar starts working. Normally I can access the command prompt but in this case all I get is this:

[image]

I was expecting the following screen:

[image]

From the System Recovery Options I can't start the command prompt, tried the Shift-F10 command from Windows Install but nothing happens.

I can get around it by reading the offline privacy statement from the Startup Repair, open a new file from Notepad and from there start an elevated cmd prompt.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

From here I tried the following commands:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

This did not work. Then I tried:

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=D:\ /offwindir=D:\Windows
```

This command did not run. Tried running `sfc /scannow` but it said another repair was running and was awaiting restart. On restart I got the same error as before.

https://www.diskpart.com/articles/boot-manager-failed-to-find-os-loader-5740.html

When I choose to open a new file in Notepad I can see all my normal files at D:\ like normal. Why can't I see the command prompt option in System Recovery Options and is there anything else I can try with?

Tried restarting the computer in F8 Safe Boot but it won't work either. I have set Automatic start delay to 5 as suggested here.

https://albarich.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/hyper-v-vm-not-recognising-f8-safe-boot-mode-keystroke/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up restoring the VM from a back up instead. The problem occurred because one team member did not shut down the VM via Hyper-V but instead shut down via the "normal" Windows start menu. This meant that he got a checkpoint on his local machine. When another team member then made changes and the first member should start up the machine again he choose to continue from checkpoint. Between this period a new `.NET Framework` and other software had been installed so Windows did nog manage to recover.